# структуры, работа с файлами

Tags: c, файлы, struct

Пытаюсь записать элементы структур в файл, однако выскакивает ошибка unknown type name 'aeroport'. Я новичок в си, подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<limits.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct cena {
  float price;
  char classs[10];
};
struct tip {
  char name[50];
  int kolvo_mest;
};
struct aeroport {
  struct tip samolet;
  struct cena bilet;
  char vzlet[80];
  char posadka[80];
};

void AddNew(void) {
  FILE * file;
  struct aeroport a;
  if (!(file = fopen("aeroport.txt", "a+"))) {
    puts("\nError");
    return;
  }
  printf("\n FROM, DESTINATION, FLIGHT, Nr.OF SEATS, PRICE, CLASS:\n");
  scanf("%s %s %s %d %f %s", & a.vzlet, & a.posadka, & a.samolet.name, & a.samolet.kolvo_mest, & a.bilet.price, & a.bilet.classs);
  fflush(stdin);
  fprintf(file, "%s %s %s %d %f %s",a.vzlet,a.posadka,a.samolet.name,a.samolet.kolvo_mest,a.bilet.price,a.bilet.classs);
  fclose(file);
}
int main() {
  AddNew();
}
```

Comment: А где вы компилируете и выполняете программу? Только что проверил, у меня всё работает без ошибок.

Comment: Используйте `typedef`, называйте поля структур и переменные более полными и английскими (американскими (это важно!)) именами, следуйте code-style языка c, а то на код невозможно смотреть!

Comment: Вам только надо переписать 38 строку ```scanf("%s %s %s %d %f %s", a.vzlet, a.posadka, a.samolet.name, &a.samolet.kolvo_mest, &a.bilet.price, a.bilet.classs);```. В scanf адрес (то есть ставится символ & перед аргументом) передаётся только в том случае, когда это переменная. Перед массивом (a.vzlet, a.posadka и т.д.) такой знак не ставится, так как вы, передавая имя массива, передаёте указатель (то есть адрес) на этот самый массив.

Comment: И я бы вам посоветовал сменить книгу или курс. Вот это ```fflush(stdin);``` обычно новичкам не предлагают использовать.

Comment: И тем более, зачем Вам вообще ```fflush(stdin)```?